# C++ - custom matrix struct

Tags: c++

I need to use matrices and I am using this kind of declaration, for example for int data type:

```
std::vector < vector <int>> my2Dvec(rows, vector <int> (cols));
```

But now I would like to use it for multiple data types, so I declared this template:

```
template <typename T>
struct matrix
{
    int col, row;
    std::vector <std::vector <T>> data;

    matrix(int c, int r) : col(c), row(r), data(col, std::vector <T> (row))
    {
        ;
    }
};
```

So I can use it as as:

```
matrix <int> m(10, 10);
...
m.data[1][2] = 0;
```

Now, how can I use (if possible) :

```
m[i][j] = someValue;
```

? How to implement such a feature ?

Comment: Since you are new to this, you might want to simplify it by using the ()-operator instead of the []-operator with two parameters. That is, you simply go with T& operator()(const uint x, const uint y){return data[x][y];}, T operator()(const uint x, const uint y) const{return data[x][y];}, which results in accesses like m(i,j) = someValue;. Might be more readable than the proxy method. In any case, you want to protect the subvectors - m[i].resize(3) should not work. For that reason, you might want to do it as a class with all attributes being private instead of a structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to implement a `[]` operator that returns a reference to a row:

```
std::vector<T> & operator[](int i) {
    return data[i];
}
```

As `operator []` is already defined on a vector, that will be enough.

---

A point on encapsulation.

This can be used that way, because as it is declared as a struct, with a public implementation, there is no encapsulation here. If `matrix` has hidden its implementation (which is the normal C++ way), you should simply declare a `Row<T>` type that implements `operator []`. This is nothing more than [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and even if it is more used on dynamic languages like Python or Ruby, it can help even in C++.

Here is an example respecting the encapsulation through duck typing:

```
/*
class Matrix represents a matrix
operator[](int i) returns a reference to the ith Row
Row is an internal type that simply defines the operator[](int j) to return
the ith element in a Row (which is a T&)
*/
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
    // implementation
    int col, row;
    typedef std::vector<T> Row;

    std::vector<Row> data;

public: // interface
    Matrix(int c, int r): row(r), col(c), data(c, std::vector<T>(r)) {}

    // allow to use matrix[i][j]
    Row & operator[](int i) {
        return data[i];
    }
};
```

Comment: You should specify that (on an abstract level) it only (partially) works because it's a struct, if it had been a class with the vector in private, it would break the encapsulation and make code using the operator potentially linked to the implementation.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisR. solution from Serge Ballesta is not solving problem in a nice and convinient way.

Comment: @ChrisR.: You are right this breaked encapsulation. But encapsulation is possible without an explicit Proxy class. Please see my edit.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes that's nice but it doesn't change the fact that you still can access a (big)part of a private member and store a reference to it. To be fair, it's the same in the example of the proxy in the other answer and the `vec` pointer should be private to this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `operator[]` in a way that it'll return a proxy object on which you can use `operator[]` again to get a result.

Example code:

```
struct matrix
{
    struct Proxy
    {
        std::vector<int>* vec;

        Proxy(std::vector<int>* vec_)
            : vec(vec_)
        {
        }

        int& operator[](int index)
        {
            return (*vec)[index];
        }
    };

    matrix(int c, int r) : col(c), row(r), data(c, std::vector<int>(r))
    {
    }

    Proxy operator[](int index)
    {
        return Proxy(&data[index]);
    }

    int col, row;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the array-subscript operator:

```
int& operator[](std::size_t i) { return data[i]; }
```

Comment: it's not enought for 2d array.

Comment: @paweldac: sure, it's an example. One either needs to return the corresponding vector, or create a wrapper.